# Visual Studio 2019 - Connect to SQL Server via Data Gateway

Tags: c#, sql-server, gateway

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. I would like to connect to a SQL Server database through an existing Data Gateway. I've tried but I don't seem to find any way to specify the gateway. When I type the server name, I get an error because it is not accessible directly. Is there a way to specify a Data Gateway in the connection string?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the data gateway as your connection?

Comment: Yes. I tried. It was not recognized. The gateway is recognized from PowerApps and I can access the data but I can't seem to find how to use it in Visual Studio.

Comment: I suspect its not supported